# performance - How can I efficiently use Java 8 to improve performance?

Tags: java, performance, java-8

How can I efficiently write following method in Java 8? I am new to Streams API and want to use it if it really gives some performance advantage.

```
private String getValue(int bitNo, int subFieldNo) {
    String answer = null;
    Map<Integer, Element> elements = getElements();

    if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(elements) && elements.containsKey(bitNo)) {
        Element element = elements.get(bitNo);

        if (element.isSubElementsPresent()) {
            List<SubElement> subFields = element.getSubElements();
            for (SubElement subElement : subFields) {
                if (subFieldNo == subElement.getStartPosition()) {
                    answer = subElement.getFieldValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (null == answer && !element.isSubElementsPresent()) {
            answer = element.getFieldValue();
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: FYI, streams are not necessarily faster, and may actually secure slower.

Comment: Currently, the main (good) reason for using Streams is that it makes your code more concise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any benefit to use stream API in your case. you have some redundant code that you can ignore them.

1- `MapUtils.isNotEmpty(elements)` isn't necessary. you can ignore it.
2- No need to allocate temporary variable. like `subFields`

3- remove

`if (null == answer && !element.isSubElementsPresent()) {
            answer = element.getFieldValue();
 }`

and use this `answer = element.getFieldValue();`

```
private String getValue(int bitNo, int subFieldNo) {
    String answer = null;
    Map<Integer, Element> elements = getElements();

    if (elements.containsKey(bitNo)) {
        Element element = elements.get(bitNo);
        answer = element.getFieldValue();
        if (element.isSubElementsPresent()) {
            for (SubElement subElement : element.getSubElements()) {
                if (subFieldNo == subElement.getStartPosition()) {
                    answer = subElement.getFieldValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: `elements.containsKey(bitNo)` is redundant too.  However, the chances are that most of the time is spent in the loop, which cannot be improved significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Element::isSubElementsPresent` checks that `subElements` field is not null, but if you change the code so that you always have non-null field (e.g. empty list) then we can build the following pipeline

```
private String getValue(int bitNo, int subFieldNo) {
    Map<Integer, Element> elements = getElements();

    Element element = elements.get(bitNo);
    if(element == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return element.getSubElements().stream()
            .filter(se -> se.getStartPosition() == subFieldNo)
            .map(SubElement::getFieldValue)
            .findAny()
            .orElseGet(element::getFieldValue);
}
```

anyway it won't be faster than what you already have